# Iterate java set for first 1000 objects to create custom sql query

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to write an sql query which runs over a set and sees if the id is in the set but it gives the error that only 1000 items can be in the array. I'm trying to solve it but I got stuck here:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < e.getEmployeeSet().size(); i+=1000) {
                sqlQuery.append("AND employee.id");
            if(!e.incudeEmployee()){
                sqlQuery.append("NOT "); 
            }
            sqlQuery.append("IN (");
            for(Employee employee: e.getEmployeeSet().){
                sqlQuery.append(employee.getEmployeeId())
                        .append(",");
            }
            sqlQuery.deleteCharAt(sqlQuery.length()-1)
                    .append(") ");
        }
```

I still have to figure out that the first time it has to be AND id.., the other times it has to be OR ... and I have to go over the set in a way that the first time I only go over the first 1000 employee's and so on. Any clean way to fix this?

Comment: you are missing some spaces in here (like after employee.id) What is the purpose of i?

Comment: Create a temporary table where you put all those id's in.

Comment: I wanted to use the i to run over each blok of a thousand id's. I renamed everything to clearer names and removed some spaces bij accident.

Comment: I not sure if your `for-loop` makes sense. `i+=1000`?

Comment: Me neither but if the set has less than 1000 Objects it will only go once, when the size is bigger it should run it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that works is like this:

```
int counter = 1;
String queryString= "WHERE (employeeId IN ( ";
Iterator<Long> it = getEmployeeSet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (counter % 999 == 0)
     queryString= queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() - 1) + " ) or
     employeeId IN ( '" + it.next()+ "',";
  else
     queryString+= "'" + it.next() + "',";
     counter++;
}
append(queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() - 1) + " )) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your sql to be like:

```
SELECT /* or UPDATE (whatever you do) */
...
WHERE
 employee.id IN (... first thousand elements ...)
 OR
 employee.id IN (... next thousand elements ...)
 OR
 ... and so on ...
```

Your Java code will be slightly different to produce "`OR employee.id IN`" block for each thousand of ids

UPD: to make it just introduce another counter to do like (pseudo code):

```
counter=0;
for each employeeId {
  if counter equals 1000 {
    complete current IN block;
    counter=0;
    if not first thousand {
      start new OR block;
    }
    start new IN block;
  } 
  add employeeId into IN block;
  counter++;
}
```

**but important: I do not recommend go the way as you do either with or without OR blocks**

It is because construct SQL as you do is direct way to SQL injection.
To avoid it just follow simple rule:

**No any actual data must be inline in SQL String. All data must be passed to Query as parameters**

You have to use prepared SQL statement with parameters for employee.id values.

Also: Simple way is to run separate query for each 1000 ids in the loop

Comment: the thing is that the set could also be just 5 elements and I know how I want it to be I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to wirte my code in Java to what you said here.

Comment: PLS look at answer Update

Comment: The problem is that the counter could be 5 or 5000, so it needs to be fully generic.

Comment: It is not a problem. `for each employeeId ` is where those 5 or 5000 counts. 1000 is fixed counter because of SQL. if there are less than 1000 so, who cares? There will be one call or one OR block with actual number of ids. Still it is better to do not put values into SQL, but use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sql allows upto 1000 list values in SQL statements. And it is not an efficient way of including the list in IN clause.

Better store data in a temporary table and add join in your query.

Temporary table creation :

create table temp_emprecords as
select * from a, b,c 
where clause...;

Now add the temp_emprecords table in your query and join with employee id.

select * 
  from employee emp,
       temp_emprecords tmp
 where emp.id = tmp.id;